# How to run individual tests in NUnit ConsoleRunner 3.4.1 with `--test=NAMES` argument

Tags: nunit-console

How can I execute just a single test case through the NUnit ConsoleRunner using the `--test=NAMES` argument.

If I right click on a test case in Visual Studio and 'Copy' this is the information regarding the test.

```
Test Name:  MakePaymentToAccountViaPayPal
Test FullName:  POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite.ExistingUserTestSuite("firefox").MakePaymentToAccountViaPayPal
Test Source:    c:\git\POMAuctivaTest\POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite\ExistingUserTestSuite.cs : line 263
Test Outcome:   Not Run
Test Duration:  0:00:00
```

Here are some of the different ways I tried to run the tests.

[image]

I have tried with both the `Test Name` and the `Test FullName` and both attempts don't actually run the test cases. I have a feeling the issue is with the string being passed as a parameter but I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have just tried this, looks like you just need to escape the quotation marks. So use:

```
--test=POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite.ExistingUserTestSuite(\"firefox\").MakePaymentToAccountViaPayPal
```